# Porting CView drawing to HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, mfc, cview

I have an MFC Windows application and I'm doing some research to see whether the software can be ported to a web app.  The MFC app has a few CView-based windows that are drawn using the CDC class drawing methods.  I'm thinking I could try to port the basic logic for this code to HTML5 canvas drawing.  Does this make sense, and if so, would it be fairly straightforward?  If I go this route are there are pitfalls, problems or incompatibilities that I should be aware of?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: The standard technology to bring an MFC application to the web is ActiveX. This, however, still requires Windows to run. If you want to open your application to other platforms and go the HTML5 route, it's no longer a port, but rather a rewrite.

Comment: Fair enough, is the HTML5 canvas functionality robust enough that such a rewrite would be possible?